# NSTableView with chat bubbles

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

I need to create a NSTableView with chat bubbles like Messages app. Is there any sample code/tutorial that I can use.

I am trying to use view based NSTableView, with custom NSTableCellView. I added a background image and trying to use the following code to stretch the chat bubble:

```
 NSImage *backgroundImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Background"];
backgroundImage = [backgroundImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0f topCapHeight:22.0f];
self.backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage;
```

I am following the MCImage Category from https://github.com/drewmccormack/BackToTheMac, but the image is not getting stretched.

Comment: check below answer...

Comment: @Nag_iphone below? where?

Comment: take this   https://github.com/samsoffes/ssmessagesviewcontroller

Comment: @Nag_iphone Thanks for your response, but I need to customize a `NSTableView` with chat bubbles, not `UITableView`. Essentially I am working on a OS X app not iOS app.

Comment: I would just use 9 NSImageViews and manually size the center image view as needed.